# App crashes when switching between fragments?

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

(Edited)

I am checking information from API and based on the response I am redirecting the fragment to another fragment on getting created but my app crashes if I switch to any other fragment too fast. How can I fix this? If someone knows my answer please help me.

**This is my Fragment**

```
public class device_main extends Fragment {

    public static ApiInterface apiInterface;
    public static PrefConfig prefConfig;
    View view;

    public device_main() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        prefConfig = new PrefConfig(getActivity());
        String user_id = prefConfig.readUser_id();

            FragmentTransaction tx = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            Call<device2> call = device_main.apiInterface.getDeviceDetails(user_id);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<device2>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<device2> call, Response<device2> response) {
                    if (response.body().getResponse().equals("ok")) {
                        String device_name = response.body().getDevice_name();
                        prefConfig.write_Devicename(device_name);

                        String imei_no = response.body().getImei_no();
                        prefConfig.write_imei_no(imei_no);

                        String model_name = response.body().getModel_name();
                        prefConfig.write_model_name(model_name);

                        String created_at = response.body().getCreated_at();
                        prefConfig.write_device_createdat(created_at);

                        //    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Go to my devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        tx.replace(R.id.device_maincontent, new my_devices());
                        tx.commit();
                    } else if (response.body().getResponse().equals("no device")) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Go to add device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        tx.replace(R.id.device_maincontent, new add_device());
                        tx.commit();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<device2> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_device_main, container, false);

        return view;
    }

}
```

**This is Logcat**

Error = Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
I got an error inline 76.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1536)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1558)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:317)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:282)
    at com.xxx.xxxx.device_main$1.onResponse(device_main.java:76)
    at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$3wC8FyV4pyjrzrYL5U0mlYiviZw.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @naanu Please go through my edited question

Comment: @PraveenSP Please check my edited question

Comment: @Srishti use commitAllowingStateLoss instead of commit